# Unit тестирование и sqlite in memory

Tags: php, laravel, юнит-тесты, phpunit

Ситуация следующая:

Есть две БД из которых в коде приложения делаются выборки и в этих выборках есть таблицы, с одинаковым названием.

Для юнит-тестов была создана тестовая БД (postgresql) с двумя схемами, олицетворяющими соответствующие базы данных. Таким образом проблема с таблицами, которые имеют одинаковое название была решена.

Но, со временем, по мере написания тестов, они начинают уверенно работать медленнее. Есть идея перенести тестовую БД на SQLite In-memory, но, как в таком случае решить проблему с одинаковым названием таблиц?

Пишу на Laravel.